# what else do I need besides $cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl']=TRUE

Tags: apache, ssl, phpmyadmin

When I add to my config
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = TRUE;
trying to connect gives
phpMyAdmin - Error #2002 -
  -- The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured)

I suspect this is because the mysql server requires
--ssl-ca=... --ssl-cert=... --ssl-key=...
How do I put those into the phpMyAdmin configuration

Or is there some other problem that I'm missing?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 3):

It's all explained reasonably well in the manual; those options are configured through additional directives in config.inc.php.

See for instance http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_ssl and the few paragraphs there that follow. (Or, to be more specific, see

- http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_ssl_key,
- http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_ssl_cert,
- http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_ssl_ca,
- http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_ssl_ca_path, and
- http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_ssl_ciphers).

In my case, I was able to achieve this through adding these directives:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_cert'] = '/etc/mysql/client-cert.pem';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_ca'] = '/etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_key'] = '/etc/mysql/client-key.pem';
```

Adjusting of course for the correct paths on your local system. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the my.ini file in  ...wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.x.x and that's it this file uses the port = 3308 which is'nt the default mysql port