# Nginx with PhpMyAdmin (Secured via ssl)

Tags: php, ssl, nginx, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I've configured a webserver with Nginx. Now, I have an instance of MariaDB running with PhpMyAdmin as management gui. It is all working it suppose to. I am still learning Nginx and all webserver related things since I started last year.

I do have every app that I run protected with a SSL certificate, so is the connection for PHPMyAdmin over https everytime I visit the url where the app is located.

```
    server {
      listen 80;
      listen [::]:80;
      server_name sub.example.com;

      location / {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
      }
    }

    server {
      listen 443 ssl http2;
      listen [::]:443 ssl;
      server_name sub.example.com;

      gzip off;
      server_tokens off;

      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

      ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;

      ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
      ssl_session_tickets off;
      ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-4096.pem;

      # OCSP stapling
      ssl_stapling on;
      ssl_stapling_verify on;
      resolver 8.8.8.8;

      # SSL sessions
      ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
      ssl_session_timeout 10m;

      add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
      add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
      add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
      add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=0; includeSubDomains";

      location / {
        proxy_pass ip:port;
      }
    }
```

Still improvements possible I think, but which is my question:
Like I said, PhpMyAdmin is running over https by Nginx. But PhpMyAdmin itself is showing a message that there is a mismatch:

[This message is readable on the login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwi4b.png)

After login, I see a: [warning under database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFNxL.png)

I looked at the docs from above warning [from PhpMyAdmin itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS0tl.png)

I made the connection available to a config.user.inc.php file, and try to include the ssl lines in there. I've done a lot of research in the last couple days to fix this. With my setup such as described, is PhpMyAdmin protected, or is only serverside protected? I readed from a post somewhere that it's enough to lead the encryption by nginx only.

How can I make sure that PhpMyAdmin is running secure? Besides that, Is the documentation mentioned above deprecated for the rencent PhpMyAdmin version, or can I use that insteat. And what about the cert files, I written down two paths to the certficate files in the Nginx conf file. Which files do I need to fill in at the ssl configuration lines for PMA? I mean, are that different files because of needing more? Example [is this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663797/what-else-do-i-need-besides-cfgserversissl-true)

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_cert'] = '/etc/mysql/client-cert.pem';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_ca'] = '/etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_key'] = '/etc/mysql/client-key.pem';
```

Edit: I only have [these cert files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1ESB.png)

If I can figure it out with adding it to the pma config, which files match which line?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be misunderstanding the ssl options in the pma config.

This does not encrypt traffic between your web browser and phpmyadmin, but rather the connection between phpmyadmin and your mysql server and it has to be set up on your mysql server.

If your mysql server is only listening on localhost and your phpmyadmin and mysql servers are on the same machine, you don't need to set this.

Comment: Ok, it is good to confirm. I don 't mentioned in the post above, but I work with Docker containers, I generate webserver certificates through Docker. But as you said, it is for a connection between MySQL and PhpMyAdmin. Wat do I need to configure then to make sure that I have a secured connection?

This all is about a single server for bussiness purposes - also not local and with a domain

Comment: This depeneds on your network setup.

How do you connect to your MySQL server? Is it on a local network with all your other docker containers, or is it open to the internet?

If it's on a local network you should be okay, just ensure your firewall does not allow incoming connections from outside the local network. If your MySQL server is open to the internet, you need to set up SSL on your MySQL serer. Generate a new certificate for the MySQL server and have a look at the [MySQL docs on SSL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-encrypted-connections.html)

Comment: The server is open to the public network. But, if I need to secure MySQL with PhpMyAdmin - can I use the cert files that are combined with my Nginx setup? And which file matches which line from the last codeblock in my post?

Comment: I'm not sure what the public network is in your case, but it sounds to me like you'll need to set up SSL on your MySQL server. You don't do this in PHPMyAdmin, it needs to be done on your MySQL server itself (by editing your my.cnf file). You should probably create new certificate for your MySQL server, otherwise you could use the same certificate, but your MySQL server and Nginx needs to have the same domain name in that case.

Once you have that set up, you can configure PHPMyAdmin with $cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true;

The other options are for SSL based authentication

Comment: Allright, I have tried this. I made the openssl cert files, and added the correct paths to my.cnf When I go into my Docker Mariadb container and request the global variables like %ssl%, says have_openssl that its value is on yes. Instead, have_ssl is on disabled. I readed disabled stands for supported, but not configured well or something. And the cert paths are in the same list. But, it shows inside of my logs that the files where not be found, and a 'SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed.' What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Connect via TCP/IP instead of Socket (localhost).  That would let you verify that form of connection and let you test with and without SSL.

It may be appropriate to test from a separate physical machine, but I don't know if that will actually exercise anything different than a same-machine TCP/IP connection.

Comment: Sorry, how can I imagine that? I'm still learning, can you explain this please? I have setup a remote connection to my Docker containers, does it work the same way?

Comment: Btw, I discovered that it's most problem and the only thing (normally) why it is not showing the correct (have_ssl on YES) is because of the wrong permissions. I looked earlier at the permissions though. But, I don't have a mysql user when I look at cat /etc/passwd -so I cannot do a chown -R mysql:mysql action to the ssl dir. Do I need to make that user manually? If so, what about the password and access to mysql (mariadb)?

Comment: @Colin - adduser mysql and chown mysql... are automatically done by most installation procedures.  Creating a root password into MySQL should also be done by the installation procedure, but with the help of the user (to get the password).

Comment: I guess it is normally in the Dockerfile of the selected image. But it doesn't make the mysql user for me. Everytime I run the mariadb image, no mysql user. Any idea how I do solve above issue?